# I cannot connect to SQL Server Express using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, connection-string, sql-server-express

Can someone tell me what I am missing? I am using this connection string to connect to my database and still it won't connect:

```
Dim str As String = "Provider = .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server; Data Source=C:\Users\konin\Documents\UHMS\bin\Debug\UHMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
```

This is the process I used to get the data source:

1. right-click the database
2. select properties and click select
   data source

I hope I am clear enough. Thanks for reading.

**Edit:**

Error Message is as follows:

`unable to connect to database please contact administrator`

Comment: What error do you get when you try to connect?

Comment: this is the error 
unable to connect to database please contact administrator. I used try and cash

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the error?  I've never seen the Data Source connected to a .mdf, only with "AttachDbFilename", you might want to take a look [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005#p1) for details on Connection strings for SQL.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Database File

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)
and the file name is UHMS.mdf

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you'll need something like this:

```
Dim str As String = "Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\konin\Documents\UHMS\bin\Debug\UHMS.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
```

You'll still need to have SQL Server Express installed on your machine in order to load this *.mdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming yours is a web application... you need to place your file based database in the App_Data folder of your project for it to work. I noticed is located in the Debug folder...